# TaskDialog - no icon present

Tags: vb.net

i started to use TaskDialog from Windows API Code Pack. Everything works well besides no icon present on this dialog. Do you know why and how to make it happen?

Example coede:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim dialog As New TaskDialog()
    dialog.Caption = "Application Error"
    dialog.InstructionText = "CRASH AND BURN!"
    dialog.Text = "The application has performed an illegal action.  Thisaction has been logged and reported."
    dialog.Icon = TaskDialogStandardIcon.Error
    dialog.Cancelable = False
    dialog.DetailsExpanded = False
    dialog.DetailsCollapsedLabel = "Show Expanded Text"
    dialog.DetailsExpandedLabel = "Hide Expanded Text"
    dialog.DetailsExpandedText = "### Start of Expanded Text ###" & Environment.NewLine & "" + Environment.NewLine + "### End of Expanded Text ###"
    Dim minValue As Integer = 0
    Dim maxValue As Integer = 100
    Dim currentValue As Integer = 20
    dialog.ProgressBar = New TaskDialogProgressBar(minValue, maxValue, currentValue)
    dialog.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: You should show the code that uses this TaskDialog to let us check if there is any problem in your code.

Comment: added- no error or whatever other icon present

Comment: Shows up just fine, Red Cross of Failure in the upper left corner  Try another Windows version, I guess.

Comment: i am using windows 10. What Windows are you using? P.S Do you know how to insert hyperling within fotter text?